# Heroku run bundle update fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mime-types, stripe-payments

My app is working perfectly on my local machine but when I try to deploy/bundle update on heroku I get the following error that prevents from me from deploying.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
In Gemfile:
rails (= 3.2.17) ruby depends on
mime-types (~> 1.16) ruby
stripe (>= 0) ruby depends on
mime-types (2.3)
```

Running `bundle update` shows that I am `using mime-types 1.25.1`.  From the error message it seems that ruby stripe would need 2.3, though if that's the case shouldn't it, as a dependency be updated to 2.3?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Perhaps take a look which version of mime-types is shown in your local machine's Gemfile.lock file? Then you could specify this a dependency in your Gemfile.

Comment: @odlp I have checked the Gemfile.lock.  Do you mean like manually going `gem mime-types ~> 2.3`?  I have tried that, if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This related SO question about [gem dependency conflicts with Rails depending on old mime-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826916/rails-4-0-2-depends-on-old-mime-types-1-16-release) mentions a syntax for specifying that multiple versions of a dependency are acceptable.

You may be in luck because Stripe just released v1.15.0 which relaxes the [mime-type gem requirement in this commit](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby/commit/8b604f630b74285a85b21c99e14880dabcd7ed5d).

The dependency from Stripe is now (greater than or equal to 1.25, or under 3) - whereas in your extract it's requiring version 2.3:

`s.add_dependency('mime-types', '>= 1.25', '< 3.0')`

And from your excerpt above Rails 3.2.17 needs 1.16 or above, of a 1.x version.

So if you **specify you need Stripe v1.15.0 or greater this may fix your issue**.

`gem 'stripe', ~> 1.15`

Comment: I'm actually getting stripe right from the repository, or `gem 'stripe', :git => 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'` so it's using the latest, or 1.15, when I do `bundle update`.  I just tried swapping to `gem 'stripe', '~> 1.15'` and running `bundle update` and mime-types fails elsewhere.  `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "mime-types":
  In Gemfile:
    mail (~> 2.5.4) x86-mingw32 depends on
      mime-types (~> 1.16) x86-mingw32

    mime-types (2.3)`